# How to register a user on a mobile app that is only used for a specific organization?

Tags: android, iphone, authentication

Usually for an mobile app that anyone can register, a user just use username, password, confirmpassword to register.

But for a mobile app developed for a specific organization, only people from that organization are allowed to register on that app. How do I let people to register in this case? Say I have phone numbers of those people saved in database.

In this case, is this the right way to register user:
1. ask user to provide phone number, username, password, confirmpassword
2. use the phone number to check if this person exists in database
3. if exists, register this user, otherwise deny.

I also think if the above method should be enhanced to prevent someone from using other people's phone number to register:
1. ask user to provide phone number
2. reply a verification code to the user via SMS
3. ask user provide verification code, username, password, confirmpassword
...

I also think maybe I can just use a user's phone number and don't need his username at all. Is this appropriate?

Can anyone let me know what is the right way or common way to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. reply a verification code to the user via SMS 3. ask user provide verification code, username, password, confirmpassword ...

I think you're on the right track there, but only if you can somehow be 100% certain that every phone number in the database can receive SMS.  What about email?  Can you ask for their email address, something like **_______**@yourcompany.com where they only fill in the first part?  Then send a verification code via email.

> I also think maybe I can just use a user's phone number and don't need
>   his username at all. Is this appropriate?

Depends on your app.  There's no technical reason why a phone number can't be used as an identifier, but there may be other reasons.  Users may not like it aesthetically.  It may make it harder to recognize the identity of other users.  It may be less convenient than some other identifier.

Comment: Thank you! I assume whoever uses the app will have a mobile phone, so he can receive SMS. Also how big a risk do you think it will be if I don't do SMS verification? I ask this because there is cost sending SMS and also need to write more code...

Comment: If you don't do some kind of verification, then anybody could sign up with the app.  How big a risk that is, you will have to decide.

Comment: Thank you. I think about this more and am convinced that SMS is mandatory.